# Trouble with build dependencies when installing Plank dock from source

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to build Plank from source but I'm having some trouble with the dependencies. I'm following directions from http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Plank:Installing#Install_Dependencies.

Everything goes well until I reach `sudo apt-get build-dep plank`

Upon running that, I get the error message

`Reading package lists... Done
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`

I did some searching and it looks like I'm supposed to add a `deb-src` line in /etc/apt/sources.list but I'm not sure what URI to add. Any help would be appreciated. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I've solved my question.

I navigated to /etc/apt and ran `sudo gedit sources.list`, then uncommented all of the lines with `deb-src` and then ran `sudo apt-get update`. After that, `sudo apt-get build-dep plank` runs fine.